# USB port on my Surface 3 died. Is it possible to boot a Surface 3 from the MicroSD card to reinstall the OS?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface, micro-sd-card

Due to an electrical surge from a stuck wireless mouse USB adapter, the sole USB port on my Surface 3 shorted out and died a few weeks ago.

This Surface 3 is the "LTE" version from Verizon, not a Surface Pro 3. The original OS was Windows 8.1 Pro, but I used the "free" upgrade from MS to get to Win10.

As a result, I have lots of annoying little quirks now that a clean OS install would solve, but now I have the issue with the dead USB port. I especially now want to reload the OS since I can't get the "Creators Update" to install and I want to try it.

**Is it possible to boot a Surface 3 from the MicroSD card to reinstall the OS?**

If so, are there any special instructions needed? My Google-Fu is not turning up any answers on this. Thank you.

Comment: If the system is running Windows 10, you can Reset the installation, and choose not to keep anything.  Additionally, Windows 10 1511+ can use the Refresh feature, which downloads and then installs Windows 10.  Windows 10 1703 has a similar updated functionality also.  Have you tried to boot to the MicroSD card?

Comment: Thanks, @Ramhound. I have tried resetting the Surface, but it just fails with a *"There was a problem resetting your PC. No changes were made"* error. I will write the latest ISO to the MicroSD and try booting to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Ok, I found a way to boot from the MicroSD:

  1. Download the [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) and create a Win10 ISO.
  2. Download [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and use it to burn/write the saved ISO to your MicroSD card.
  3. Power off the Surface 3 completely. Then hold the "volume up" button and press the power button to boot into UEFI options.
  4. Disable Secure Boot and delete all secure boot keys, then exit UEFI setup.
  5. In your existing Windows 10 installation, go into Settings > Recovery > [Advanced Startup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnbi_bT2pE4). Reboot.
  6. Once in Advanced Startup > Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > Command Prompt (enter admin password).
  7. Run this command to find what is likely the MicroSD: `wmic logicaldisk get caption`
  8. Type the drive letter then colon (":"). For me it was: `D:` (may be the same but might not, you can just try a few still you see the file
     structure of the MicroSD by running `dir` (look for setup.exe)
  9. Run `setup.exe` to reinstall Windows 10!